# Back button not collapsing SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I have a android.support.v7.widget.SearchView living in my AppCompat Toolbar.

I click the Search button to expand the MenuItem's ActionView, and all is fine until I hit the device's hardware Back button. This hides the keyboard, and the SearchView's EditText loses focus and its cursor vanishes, but the item doesn't collapse back to the Search icon. Instead, the menu item to the right of the Search icon becomes focussed/highlighted, which is... not right. Pressing back again doesn't do it.

I've tried detecting the back key in various ways, such as adding an OnKeyListener to either the SearchView or its EditText, but it doesn't trigger. Pressing the Up button in the action bar does exactly what I need, so I just need to detect the Back button.

The only thing that's strange about my setup is the SearchView itself isn't in the Layout - if I add it in, it builds successfully, but crashes at Runtime. For some reason.

I have a listener for expand/collapse, collapse is only detected when the Up button is clicked, it is not triggered when the Back button is pressed.

Thanks

Here's my code setting up the SearchView:

```
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
final SearchView searchView = new MyobSearchView(activity);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menuItem, searchView);
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem, new FocusSearchFieldActionExpandListener(searchView, androidUtils));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by overriding the onBackPressed() method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        // do what you want
}
```

Comment: In the activity presumably?

Comment: Yep. In the activity.

Comment: The activity's OnBackPressed does not get called when the SearchView is expanded. So I don't believe this is an answer

Comment: `onBackPressed()` isn't called when the Keyboard is shown.... this isn't the answer.